# Windows Server 2008 R2: Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

My application is running by:

- ASP.NET
- MVC 3
- Framework 4.0

When I run the application on my computer (localhost:...) it's runs successfully.
Now, is the first time, I run application on windows server 2008 R-2.
The error is: "Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found"
What could be the problem?

(.net4 installed correctly, and csc.exe file is exists in: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0\").

Comment: can you make sure which version of .Net is running , [here is Verification Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

**Please, send complete stack trace, just like this below**:

```
"[InvalidOperationException: Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.RedistVersionInfo.GetCompilerPath(IDictionary`2 provOptions, String compilerExecutable) +8675071
   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] fileNames) +739
   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources) +3293761
   Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(CompilerParameters options, String[] sources) +64
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.Compile(String fileName, String[] sources, IEnumerable`1 assembliesToReference) +1252
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.Util.GenerateAssembly.CompileAssembly(IEnumerable`1 sourcesResources, IEnumerable`1 assembliesToReference, String assemblyName) +118
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.SetupDatabaseDefaultConnectionFactoryIfNeeded() +929
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.SetupEntityFrameworkIntegration() +80
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize(EntityFrameworkAppenderConfiguration configuration) +47
   HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProfiler.Initialize() +73
   Web4.MvcApplication.Application_Start() +17

[HttpException (0x80004005): Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12864673
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Compiler executable file csc.exe cannot be found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881540
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext "
```

If you are using HibernatingRhinos, you should try a new dll build:
http://hibernatingrhinos.com/builds like discussed in this post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhprof/XY4e3tm-ONc
It solved my issue.